# How to display checkbox in custom custom visualforce page for CPQ quote?

Tags: visualforce, xml, quote, cpq, steelbrick

I am trying to generate a quote document using custom visualforce page for steelbrick CPQ. I need to display a checkbox in a column (it does not have to be associated with any field). I tried using , HTML tags, img tags, tried saving image as a static resource and referencing it, tried using UTF codes for checkbox but nothing worked. I found this page: [Visualforce page for CPQ](https://opfocus.com/custom-visualforce-page-steelbrick-quote/) which states that **"The VisualForce component needs to be compatible with XML (specifically XSL-FO) to be compatible with CPQ document output."** I am not familiar with this standard, therefore, any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
<apex:page rendered="{!rendered}" language="{!language}" showHeader="false" 
sidebar="false" cache="false"  controller="PS_M3_OptionalSectionController" 
contentType="application/xml">

<block margin="8pt"/>

<block>
    <table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-color="#000000" border- 
     width="1px" border-style="solid" font-size="8px">
        <table-column column-width="5%"/>
        <table-column column-width="5%"/>
        <table-column column-width="{!descriptionColumnWidth}%"/>
        <table-column column-width="{!dailyRateColumnWidth}%"/>
        <table-column column-width="{!weeklyRateColumnWidth}%"/>
        <table-column column-width="{!monthlyRateColumnWidth}%"/>
        <table-column column-width="{!totalPriceColumnWidth}%"/> 

        <table-header>
            <table-row line-height="14px" font-weight="bold" text- 
             align="left" color="#000000" background-color="#FED5B3">
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt"><block> 
                 {!$Label.Quantity}</block></table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt"><block> 
                 {!$Label.Quantity}</block></table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt"><block> 
                  {!$Label.PFH_Description}</block></table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt" text- 
                 align="right">
                    <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayDailyRate}" 
                        value="{!$Label.Daily_rate_1}"></apex:outputText> 
                      </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt" text- 
                   align="right">
                    <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayWeeklyRate}" 
                          value="{!$Label.Weekly_Rate}"></apex:outputText> 
                       </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt" text- 
          align="right">
                    <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayMonthlyRate}" 
     value="{!$Label.Monthly_Rate}"></apex:outputText></block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" margin="3pt" text- 
align="right">
                    <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayTotalPrice}" value="{!$Label.Total_Price}"></apex:outputText></block>
                </table-cell>
            </table-row>
        </table-header>

        <table-body>
            <apex:repeat var="line" value="{!optionalCharges_String}">
                <table-row line-height="9px">
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                        <!--<img src="{!$Resource.Checkbox}" alt ="" border="3"/>-->

                       <block margin="3pt">
                       <!--- CHECKBOX REQUIRED-->
                        <!--<img src='/img/func_icons/util/lock12.gif'/>-->

                        <!--<image>

                        <!--</image>-->
                        <!--<image>
                        <img src= "/resource/1561113417000/Checkbox"/>
                        </image>-->
                        <!--{!$Resource.Checkbox}-->
                        <!--<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Checkbox}"/>-->
                        <!--<c:logo></c:logo>-->
                        <!--<input type= "checkbox" value ="checked"/>-->
                       <!-- <block></block>
                        <!--<apex:outputText value="{!if(line.optional,true,false)}">-->
                        <!--<img src="/resource/1561113417000/Checkbox "/>-->
                        <!--<apex:image url="{!$Resource.Checkbox}"/>-->
                        <!--<apex:outputText>U+2610;
                       </apex:outputText>-->
                        <!--<img src="/img/oocss/box_faq_folded_corner.png"/>-->
                       <!--<apex:outputText value="{!HTMLENCODE('&#x25a2')}"/>

                       <!--GIF89 <img src = "/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>-->
                       <!--<block>{!$Resource.Checkbox}</block>-->
                      </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <block><apex:outputText value="{!line.quantity}"/></block>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <apex:repeat var="desc" value="{!line.description}">
                                <block>{!HTMLENCODE(desc)}</block>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayDailyRate}" value="{!line.dailyRate}"/></block>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayWeeklyRate}" value="{!line.weeklyRate}"/></block>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayMonthlyRate}" value="{!line.monthlyRate}"/></block>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                    <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                        <block margin="3pt">
                            <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayTotalPrice}" value="{!line.totalPrice}"/></block>
                        </block>
                    </table-cell>
                </table-row>
            </apex:repeat>
            <table-row line-height="9px">
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                        <block>{!$Label.TOTAL}</block>

                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                        <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayDailyRate}" value="{!totalDailyRate_String}"/></block>
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                        <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayWeeklyRate}" value="{!totalWeeklyRate_String}"/></block>
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                        <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayMonthlyRate}" value="{!totalMonthlyRate_String}"/></block>
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
                <table-cell border="1px solid black" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" text-align="right">
                    <block margin="3pt">
                        <block><apex:outputText rendered="{!displayTotalPrice}" value="{!totalPrice_String}"/></block>
                    </block>
                </table-cell>
            </table-row>
        </table-body>
    </table>
</block>

<block margin="8pt"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to display a checkbox in a custom visualforce page for a Salesforce CPQ quote template section - and you say you tried HTML and img tags.

You got the right idea, only that in `<xls-fo>` the syntax to include an image is different:

The syntax to include an image (of your checked-box) is:

```
<external-graphic src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"  content-height="scale-to-fit" height="1.5in"  content-width="2.00in" scaling="non-uniform"/>
```

or rather with an actual checkbox:

```
<external-graphic src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11351528/51387695-f564d000-1b4c-11e9-817d-5e6280f997d0.png" width="13px" height="13px"/>
```

Hope that helps - please replace the checkbox URL with your own.